# Android on both Linux and Mac

Tags: android

I can android SDK for Linux and Mac from their sites. After installation in Linux they asked me to downloa Platforms and Other Packages

[image]

I have already downloaded in my Linux machine. Now I have a Mac, so I have downloaded the SDK they provided. My question is can I use the Platforms and Other Packages that I already downloaded for mac

Comment: No you can not use MAC SDK on Linux and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `platform-tools/` is platform-specific, and so you definitely need to download those separately for each OS.

Most of the other components should be platform-neutral. However, I have not tried copying that material between operating systems, and so I cannot be certain that it will work correctly. I would recommend that you just download the stuff again.